# Optimizing ACT_RU_JOB Table in ACTIVITI Engine

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, activiti

We're using Activiti version 5.15.1 with timers in our workflow which sends reminders to users who are in the workflow. Problem is that we're creating jobs in ACT_RU_JOB table and even though there are only 45k odd rows in ACT_RU_JOB table, we're constantly getting slow query alert from the queries running on ACT_RU_JOB table.

A sample slow query alert from database looks like this:

```
    ### 253 Queries 
    ### Taking 1.001277 to 1.567178 seconds to complete

    SET timestamp=XXX;
    select RES.*
        from ACT_RU_JOB RES
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION PI ON PI.ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_
        where (RES.TYPE_ = 'XXX')
          and (RES.DUEDATE_ is not null)
          and (RES.DUEDATE_ < 'XXX')
          and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < 'XXX')
          and (RES.RETRIES_  > XXX)
          and (
            (RES.EXECUTION_ID_ is null)
            or 
            (PI.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = XXX)    
          )
        order by DUEDATE_;


    ### 225 Queries 
    ### Taking 1.000308 to 1.255745 seconds to complete

    SET timestamp=XXX;
    select RES.*  
        from ACT_RU_JOB RES
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION PI ON PI.ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_
        where (RETRIES_ > XXX)
          and (DUEDATE_ is null or DUEDATE_ <= 'XXX')
          and (LOCK_OWNER_ is null or LOCK_EXP_TIME_ <= 'XXX')
          and (
              (RES.EXECUTION_ID_ is null)
            or 
            (PI.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = XXX)     
          )  
        LIMIT XXX OFFSET XXX;
```

The actual query looks something like this:

```
select RES.*
        from ACT_RU_JOB RES
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION PI ON PI.ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_
        where (RES.TYPE_ = 'timer')
          and (RES.DUEDATE_ is not null)
          and (RES.DUEDATE_ < '2015-07-15 10:42:47.464')
          and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < '2015-07-15 10:42:47.464')
          and (RES.RETRIES_  > 0)
          and (
            (RES.EXECUTION_ID_ is null)
            or 
            (PI.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1)    
          )
        order by DUEDATE_;

    select RES.*
    from ACT_RU_JOB RES
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION PI ON PI.ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_
    where (RETRIES_ > 0)
      and (DUEDATE_ is null or DUEDATE_ <= '2015-04-17 14:59:09.982')
      and (LOCK_OWNER_ is null or LOCK_EXP_TIME_ <= '2015-04-17 14:59:09.982')
      and (
          (RES.EXECUTION_ID_ is null)
        or
        (PI.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1)
      )
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0;

    select RES.*
        from ACT_RU_JOB RES
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ACT_RU_EXECUTION PI ON PI.ID_ = RES.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_
        where (RES.TYPE_ = 'timer')
          and (RES.DUEDATE_ is not null)
          and (RES.DUEDATE_ < '2015-04-20 09:12:13.551')
          and (RES.LOCK_OWNER_ is null or RES.LOCK_EXP_TIME_ < '2015-04-20 09:12:13.551')
          and (RES.RETRIES_  > 0)
          and (
            (RES.EXECUTION_ID_ is null)
            or
            (PI.SUSPENSION_STATE_ = 1)
          )
        order by DUEDATE_;
```

Structure of Table ACT_RU_JOB

```
    ID_ varchar(64) NO  PRI NULL  
    REV_  int(11) YES   NULL  
    TYPE_ varchar(255)  NO  MUL NULL  
    LOCK_EXP_TIME_  timestamp(3)  YES   NULL  
    LOCK_OWNER_ varchar(255)  YES   NULL  
    EXCLUSIVE_  tinyint(1)  YES   NULL  
    EXECUTION_ID_ varchar(64) YES   NULL  
    PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_  varchar(64) YES   NULL  
    PROC_DEF_ID_  varchar(64) YES   NULL  
    RETRIES_  int(11) YES MUL NULL  
    EXCEPTION_STACK_ID_ varchar(64) YES MUL NULL  
    EXCEPTION_MSG_  varchar(4000) YES   NULL  
    DUEDATE_  timestamp(3)  YES   NULL  
    REPEAT_ varchar(255)  YES   NULL  
    HANDLER_TYPE_ varchar(255)  YES   NULL  
    HANDLER_CFG_  varchar(4000) YES   NULL  
    TENANT_ID_  varchar(255)  YES
```

Structure of ACT_RU_EXECUTION is as follows:

```
    ID_ varchar(64) NO  PRI NULL  
    REV_  int(11) YES   NULL  
    TYPE_ varchar(255)  NO  MUL NULL  
    LOCK_EXP_TIME_  timestamp(3)  YES   NULL  
    LOCK_OWNER_ varchar(255)  YES   NULL  
    EXCLUSIVE_  tinyint(1)  YES   NULL  
    EXECUTION_ID_ varchar(64) YES   NULL  
    PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_  varchar(64) YES   NULL  
    PROC_DEF_ID_  varchar(64) YES   NULL  
    RETRIES_  int(11) YES MUL NULL  
    EXCEPTION_STACK_ID_ varchar(64) YES MUL NULL  
    EXCEPTION_MSG_  varchar(4000) YES   NULL  
    DUEDATE_  timestamp(3)  YES   NULL  
    REPEAT_ varchar(255)  YES   NULL  
    HANDLER_TYPE_ varchar(255)  YES   NULL  
    HANDLER_CFG_  varchar(4000) YES   NULL  
    TENANT_ID_  varchar(255)  YES
```

We've added two composite indices on ACT_RU_JOB (TYPE_, EXECUTION_ID_, LOCK_OWNER_, RETRIES_, LOCK_EXP_TIME_, DUEDATE_) and (RETRIES_,EXECUTION_ID_, LOCK_EXP_TIME_,DUEDATE_) but that doesn't seem to help our cause. Any pointers on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
      and (RES.DUEDATE_ is not null)
      and (RES.DUEDATE_ < 'XXX')
```

can be simplified to just

```
      and (RES.DUEDATE_ < 'XXX')
```

This composite index would help with both the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`:

```
INDEX(TYPE_, DUEDATE_)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what you are working with -- ENGINE, INDEXes (`mul` is too vague), etc.

I don't want to discuss the second query because it has `LIMIT` without and `ORDER BY`, hence returns semi-random row(s).